# How to support Forms Authentication using AD for external/internet users & direct login for intranet users using WEB API2?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api2

I've a requirement in one of my Asp.Net WEBAPI2 project where I need to auto login user (using Windows Authentication) if they are trying to access the application from within the domain. And if the user tries to access the application outside domain I need to provide user with a login page which will use Forms Authentication using AD.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use claims based AD authentication for all websites (internal and external)

Check out this example:
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-groupclaims

You don't need to create your own forms based authentication, and the location of the user isn't important anymore.

This will also solve the problem that you need `windows authentication` and `anonymous authentication`  at the same time in your application (or creating 2 versions)